# ipython nbcovert does not show latex formulas

Tags: markdown, jupyter-notebook

I'm doing a presentation in the ipython notebook 2.1.0 (and running it from Canopy).

To generate the presentation, I use the command

```
ipython nbconvert test.ipynb --to slides --post serve
```

The latex formulas in the notebooks are shown correctly but I get in the convertion
wrong latex formulas, for example, writting

```
$\zeta$-> \(\zeta\)
```

Once it is shown the presentation in the browser.

Is there any trick I should use to display the formulas correctly?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you saying that your source says `$\zeta$`, but it renders in the browser as `\(\zeta\)` instead of `ζ`?

Comment: yes, this is exactly what is happening, in the notebook, it renders ok, but not when I do the nbconvert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) isn't loading properly. Perhaps you are affected by [this bug](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/6407)?

This was fixed by [pull request 6395](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/6395), which was merged on September 4, 2014. There hasn't been a release since then, but if you [install the development version iPython from Git](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/install/install.html#installing-the-development-version) you should find that your issue is fixed:

> ```
> git clone --recursive https://github.com/ipython/ipython.git
> cd ipython
> python setup.py install
> ```

If you'd prefer to use `pip`, you should be able to install the development version of `ipython` like this:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/ipython/ipython.git@master#egg=ipython
```

If you want to upgrade an existing `pip`-installed `ipython`, add the `--upgrade` flag after `install`.

Comment: I have installed already the ipython (through pip, I think), does it affect the current one if I install the development version?

Comment: @user2820579, hard to answer without more detail. If you want to keep both versions installed, I recommend using `virtualenv`s (you may be doing this already). If you'd prefer simply to upgrade your installed `ipython` to the development version, use the updated instructions in my answer.

Comment: I installed a virtualenv and then I did `./pip install git+https://github.com/ipython/ipython.git@master#egg=ipython`.
After installing some extra dependecies and `--post serve` the notebook I'm still finding the bug

Comment: You're definitely running the correct version? What does `ipython --version` give?

Comment: If you inspect the page when you're running your presentation (e.g., using Ctrl+Shift+I), do you see MathJax loading properly? Any errors in the console?

Comment: Using the firefox console I found this:

`ReferenceError: MathJax is not defined`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61305/discussion-between-chris-and-user2820579).